# Passing php variables through the parameter to a javascript trigger function, PHP, JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to pass 2 variables through a php function's parameters to be use by the javascript's trigger function but the javascript's trigger function is not accepting the 2 variables. Not sure what I did wrong. Please take a look:

> trigger.php

```
<?php

function trigger($type,$name) {

echo "<script>";

echo "

$(function(){
  $('$type[name=$name]').trigger('change');
});

";

echo "</script>";

}

?>
```

Comment: what does the output look like on your page?

Comment: @cmorrissey Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ']'

Comment: @cmorrissey I assume it's talking about the name=$name, part. But not sure what I did wrong there.

Comment: try to escape `$(function(){` to `\$(function(){` and `$('$type[name` to `\$('$type[name` ?I'm not sure the $ can be escaped or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `"` which attempt to parse the variables in the string, if you switch to `'` the `$` of the jQuery won't be parsed and you can concat your variables with `.`

```
function trigger($type,$name) {

echo '<script>';

echo '

$(function(){
  $(\'' . $type . '[name=' . $name . ']\').trigger(\'change\');
});

';

echo '</script>';

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It works. I have to admit, at this point it gets really confusing when mixing php and javascript types into a single function.